# DNS Search suffix is being ignored

Tags: windows, powershell, client, vpn, openvpn

I'm on a Windows 10 laptop and am receiving the following behaviour:

When I check the DNS Search Suffix List:

```
PS C:\> Get-DnsClientGlobalSetting

UseSuffixSearchList : True
SuffixSearchList    : {domain1.co.uk, domain2.com, domain3.box}
UseDevolution       : True
DevolutionLevel     : 0
```

When I resolve the hostname without the suffix:

```
PS C:\> Resolve-DnsName -Name hostname1
Resolve-DnsName : hostname1 : DNS name does not exist
At line:1 char:1
+ Resolve-DnsName -Name hostname1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (hostname1:String) [Resolve-DnsName], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DNS_ERROR_RCODE_NAME_ERROR,Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.ResolveDnsName
```

When I resolve the hostname with the suffix manually specified:

```
PS C:\> Resolve-DnsName -Name hostname1.domain2.com 

Name                                           Type   TTL   Section    IPAddress                                
----                                           ----   ---   -------    ---------                                
hostname1.domain2.com            A      300   Answer     10.10.10.234
hostname1.domain2.com            A      300   Answer     10.10.11.197
```

Why isn't the suffix "domain2.com" being used to resolve "hostname1" to the IP addresses, as is possible when the suffix is added manually? This should be hapenning automatically, shouldn't it?

I've tried running

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

And I've tried restarting, but it still won't take. What's happening here?

Note: The domain2.com suffix is added automatically when I connect to an Open VPN endpoint, and is specified in the OpenVPN configuration file as:

> dhcp-option DOMAIN domain2.com

I've seen posts saying that it's to do with the binding order, and that you can solve this (DNS leak) by increasing the metric for the VPC NIC, so I wrote a script to increase the metric of that card to be the highest out of all cards:

```
$HighestMetric = ((Get-NetIPInterface).InterfaceMetric | Sort-Object -Descending)[0]
$VpcAdapter = Get-NetAdapter | Where-Object -Property InterfaceDescription -Match "TAP"
$currentMetric = (Get-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias $VpcAdapter.InterfaceAlias -AddressFamily IPv4).InterfaceMetric
Set-NetIPInterface -InterfaceAlias $VpcAdapter.InterfaceAlias -InterfaceMetric ($HighestMetric +1)
```

But that still hasn't solved the issue

Comment: I only get your message when I use `-DnsOnly` switch. Can you run it again using `Resolve-DnsName -Name hostname1 -DnsOnly:$false`?

Comment: That's a useful switch, thanks. But unfortunately I still get the same error.